# spark streaming stdin input / reading from unix utility output

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to build a Spark Streaming app that reads in a unix utility's output stream. What's the best way to create DStream from stdin? How do I redirect / pipe the stream output of the external utility into Spark Streaming DStream? I work with Scala, and I realize rdd.pipe() might not help since it works with command that reads from an rdd in the first place. Thanks!

My original question was posted to the Spark users' mailing list: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-Streaming-reads-from-stdin-or-output-from-command-line-utility-td23289.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use netcat command in linux .Pipe your program output to the netcat.

`./your-executable | nc -l <portnumber>`

And then you can create DStream using the same port number

`ssc.socketTextStream(cassandraHost, portNum)`